# How to insert await to async method with quick fix (using ReSharper)

Tags: resharper

In some legacy versions of ReSharper it was possible to `alt` + `enter` to insert `await` to invocation of async method. How to enable this feature in current versions?

Example:

```
dog.WoofAsync(); // alt+enter to insert await
```

Comment: It is still available. Check if you have not turned off compiler warning CS4014 "ASync method invocation without await expression"

Comment: @IvanSerduk I have it tuned on, such a method is underlined. ReSharper treats it as a warning.

Comment: Please, create a request in ReSharper's bug tracker ( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP ) with a sample code